# Android - перенаправление Broadcast'a в Activity

Tags: android, java, broadcast-receiver

Добрый день! Пишу плеер, и очень хочется сделать функцию, чтобы пользователь мог переключать треки кнопками клавиатуры/гарнитуры. Пока что накодил ресивер:

```
public class RemoteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
public RemoteReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent i)
{
    new Utilities(ctx).Log("onReceive");
    try
    {
        KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)i.getSerializableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        switch (ke.getKeyCode())
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                // ???
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
                // ???
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                // ???
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
}
}
```

Этот ресивер я инициализирую в MainActivity в методе onCreate:

```
    IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
    i.setPriority(2147483647);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 10) registerReceiver(new RemoteReceiver(), i);
    else mAudioMan.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(this, RemoteReceiver.class.getName()));
```

В свёрнутом состоянии, если нажать на кнопку, то в логах появляется `onReceive`, значит ресивер работает.
Вопрос состоит в том, как мне перенаправить нажатие в MainActivity? Пробовал обращаться напрямую через конструкторы и провоцировать нажатие кнопок - не помогло(наверно потому что при сворачивании кнопки деактивируются).

**UPD** Решил проблему: перенёс ресивер в MainActivity, сделал его статичным. Дальше исправил `i.getSerializableExtra(...)` на `i.getParcelableExtra(...)`, тем самым исправив NPE. А при нажатии просто использовал PendingIntent и ещё один ресивер (внутри самой активити). Спасибо тем, кто нашёл время помочь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только что догадался залезть в Log.w - там написано, что `KeyEvent ke` - null. В чём может быть дело? Всё же определено и правильно передано.

**UPD** нужно было не `i.getSerializableExtra`, a `i.getParcelableExtra`

Answer (score 0):

как на счет переопределить класс Application, и хранить статическую ссылку на нужную Активити в этом классе?  
И как бы, программно вызывать клики у кнопок?? Зачем? Достаточно всего лиш вынести все, что происходит в OnClick в др. функцию, и вызывать ее...